# I want to add a node to a child in Firebase but when I put add value, it erases all the other data previously sent to the Databse - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a new node for the `.child("users")` but am struggling to upload it. The thing is that in the first step of the signup, the users sign up with the `email`, `username`, and `password`. The `email` and `username` are sent to the `.child("users")` successfully. Afterwards, the user is sent to a new `ViewController` where they're supposed to chose a profile picture. Here's the tricky thing. The photo url *does save* but **deletes the previously saved data** leaving only the photo url.

Here's what happens through the process

[1.) user3 is successfully added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqntW.png)

[2.) Photo url is successfully added, and user and email in process of being deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjUIX.png)

[3.) Only phot url remains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXQAq.png)

Here's my code. Thanks a lot!

```
 var selectedProfileImage : UIImage!

@IBAction func doneButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

            ProgressHUD.show("En Proceso...")
            let storage = Storage.storage()
            let storageRef = storage.reference()
            //photo idstring gives us a unique string for any given time of the day. Garantied unique string
            let photoIdString = "\(NSUUID().uuidString).jpg"
            let imageReference = storageRef.child("profileImages").child(photoIdString)
            if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedProfileImage, 0.7) {
                imageReference.putData(imageData).observe(.success) { (snapshot) in
                    imageReference.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in

                        if let downloadUrl = url {
                            let directoryURL : NSURL = downloadUrl as NSURL
                            let urlString:String = directoryURL.absoluteString!
                            self.sendDataToUserDatabase(photoUrl: urlString)
                                ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Tu imagen ha sido publicada!")
                                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toHomeView", sender: self)
                        }
                        else {
                            print("couldn't get profile image url")
                            ProgressHUD.showError("No hemos podido subir tu foto de perfil. Intenta más tarde")
                            return
                        }
                    })
                }
        }

    }

    //FUNCS

    func sendDataToUserDatabase(photoUrl: String) {
        //por the time being photoUrl:String - wasn't added because I can't get the downloadURL
        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        let usersReference = ref.child("users")
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let newUserReference = usersReference.child(uid!)
        newUserReference.setValue(["photoUrl": photoUrl]) { (error, ref) in
            if error != nil {
                ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Tu imagen ha sido publicada!")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toHomeView", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `setValue` replaces all existing data in the location. If you only want to update specific child nodes/properties, call `updateChildValues`:

```
newUserReference.updateChildValues(["photoUrl": photoUrl]) { (error, ref) in
    ...
}
```

Also see the [Firebase documentation on updating specific children](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).

Comment: I had tried this before and it didn't work, but now that I've tried it again it works perfectly fine! Thanks!

Comment: I will do that just as soon as I have a 15 reputation!

Comment: There is no minimum reputation to accept an answer to a question you ask. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the value of its parent node. Try setting like this:

```
 Database.database().reference().ref("users/\(uid)/photoUrl").setValue(photoUrl) { (error, ref) in
            if error != nil {
                ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Tu imagen ha sido publicada!")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toHomeView", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

By setting the value for `photoUrl`, you are changing its value for `photoUrl` node rather than the `userID` node itself.

For the first time, since there is no `photoUrl` node there, Firebase will automatically create a new `photoUrl` node and sets its value.

Comment: I actually get - Cannot call value of non-function type 'DatabaseReference'. I've already checked my pods and they are well installed :/ what do you think might be the error?